# Error reading a parquet file with pyspark " Required field 'version' was not found in serialized data! "

Tags: pyspark, parquet, apache-spark-2.0

I am using pyspark 2.0 in a Hadoop cluster with the Hortonworks HDP 2.5.
I try to read a parquet file with:

```
dfsms = spark.read.parquet("/projects/data/parquetfolder")
```

I can see the header of the data and print several lines. But when I try something like:

```
dfsms.count()
dfsms.describe().show()
```

I obtain the following error:

```
java.io.IOException: can not read class org.apache.parquet.format.FileMetaData: Required field 'version' was not found in serialized data! Struct: FileMetaData(version:0, schema:null, num_rows:0, row_groups:null)


    --------------------------------------------------------------------------
Py4JJavaError                             Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-7-0717f4acccb0> in <module>()
      1 #dfsms.show(10)
      2 
----> 3 dfsms.count()

/usr/hdp/2.5.0.0-1245/spark2/python/pyspark/sql/dataframe.py in count(self)
    297         2
    298         """
--> 299         return int(self._jdf.count())
    300 
    301     @ignore_unicode_prefix

/usr/hdp/2.5.0.0-1245/spark2/python/lib/py4j-0.10.1-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py in __call__(self, *args)
    931         answer = self.gateway_client.send_command(command)
    932         return_value = get_return_value(
--> 933             answer, self.gateway_client, self.target_id, self.name)
    934 
    935         for temp_arg in temp_args:

/usr/hdp/2.5.0.0-1245/spark2/python/pyspark/sql/utils.py in deco(*a, **kw)
     61     def deco(*a, **kw):
     62         try:
---> 63             return f(*a, **kw)
     64         except py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError as e:
     65             s = e.java_exception.toString()

/usr/hdp/2.5.0.0-1245/spark2/python/lib/py4j-0.10.1-src.zip/py4j/protocol.py in get_return_value(answer, gateway_client, target_id, name)
    310                 raise Py4JJavaError(
    311                     "An error occurred while calling {0}{1}{2}.\n".
--> 312                     format(target_id, ".", name), value)
    313             else:
    314                 raise Py4JError(

Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o46.count.
: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 5 in stage 1.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 5.3 in stage 1.0 (TID 42, worker12.): java.io.IOException: can not read class org.apache.parquet.format.FileMetaData: Required field 'version' was not found in serialized data! Struct: FileMetaData(version:0, schema:null, num_rows:0, row_groups:null)
```

Comment: did you figure out how to resolve this? I ran into the same error today.